# How to retrieve frequency of a term in elastic search using python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have to find the frequency of a term in present across all the matching  documents which have that term, for example: "sky". For ex: if doc1 has a sentence,

> "sky is blue. sky is blue."

and doc2 has a sentence,

> "the plane is flying in the sky".

Then the total frequency of the term "sky" should be 3. I found termvectors as mentioned here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html
and it's Python API, http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=term%20vector#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.termvectors

But when I tried implementing it:

`es.search(index="abc", body={"from":0, "size":0,"term vectors":{"fields":["sky"],"field_statistics":"true"}})`

I get an error:

> raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
>   elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, u'parsing_exception', u'Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [term vectors].')

Answer (score 3):

For my purposes I never use `termvector`, because I retrieve statistics after other processing, so I use `mtermvector`. It is the same of `termvector`, but it works with a list of ids. If you have a list of all the ids of your documents that match "sky" you could proceed in that way:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

index = "abc"
my_doc_type ="your_doc_type"
ids = []

result = es.search(
    index="abc", 
    doc_type=my_doc_type, 
    body={
        "query": {
            "term": {
                "field":  "sky"
            }
        }
    }
)     


for res in result['hits']['hits']:
    ids.append(res['_id'])




for doc in es.mtermvectors(
        index=index,
        doc_type=doc_type,
        body=dict(
            ids=ids,
            parameters=dict(
                term_statistics=True,
                field_statistics=True,
                fields=fields
                )
        )
)['docs']:
    fields = doc['term_vectors']
    terms = field['terms']
    tf = vec["term_freq"]
    df = vec["doc_freq"]
```

Comment: what does fields=fields means?

Comment: @AmoghMishra Sorry, I have copied too fast from my code. Fields is my var with all the fields that I would like to return. I have passed that list to the fields param of mtermvector method . You could read better here in the doc http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=mtermvector#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.mtermvectors

Comment: what is vec["term_freq"] and vec["doc_freq"]?Did you initialized them before?

Answer (score 0):

look at this page -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html#_behaviour

example:

```
PUT /twitter/_doc/1
{
  "fullname" : "John Doe",
  "text" : "twitter test test test "
}

PUT /twitter/_doc/2
{
  "fullname" : "Jane Doe",
  "text" : "Another twitter test ..."
}
GET /twitter/_doc/1/_termvectors
{
  "fields" : ["text"],
  "offsets" : true,
  "payloads" : true,
  "positions" : true,
  "term_statistics" : true,
  "field_statistics" : true
}
```

"fields" should contain name of your fields in document ("text", "fullname" or something like this). and this request returns statistics for all words. I'm not sure if you can get statistics for the selected word