# Elasticsearch find a word from local json file [PYTHON]

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I try to use Elasticsearch due to get some values and frequencies from local json file with python. 
Json file has multiple terms shown as below;

```
[{"id": "251088", "tweet": "lorem ipsum", "username": "Ahmet"},
{"id": "251059", "tweet": "bla bla bla","username": "Ali", },
...
]
```

The json file consists approximately 500K tweets and info.
I aim to get term frequency with elasticsearch faster.

```
import requests, json, os
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])
i = 1
f = open("tweets_test.json")
docket_content = f.read()
#print(docket_content)


# only wait for 1 second, regardless of the client's default
es.cluster.health(wait_for_status='yellow', request_timeout=1)

es.index(index='tweets', ignore=[400, 404], doc_type='docket', id=i, body=json.loads(docket_content))

res = es.search(index="tweets", doc_type="docket", body={"query": {"match": {"tweet": "any-word"}}})
print("%d documents found" % res['hits']['total'])
for doc in res['hits']['hits']:
    print("%s) %s" % (doc['_id'], doc['_source']['content']))
```

the output is;

```
0 documents found 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

- Why didn't work this code?
- Am I wrong platform to getting term frequency?

Comment: According you, what you expect searching for "ve"? If you have a default mapping, the field tweet assumes standard analyzer. If you search for "ve" in this field, es should retrieve all the "ve" term or "ve" as stem . Why you expect "ve" terms in your text?

Comment: "ve" is not important term. I has just try to find anyword.

Comment: Although "ve" words is absolutely exist in most tweets. But ES returns any docs. I didnt understand this output. Actually, the main problem is to find word frequencies in all tweets using ES. Due to learn ES, I just  try to some exercises (find a word)

Comment: to find word frequencies in all tweets, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085839/how-to-retrieve-frequency-of-a-term-in-elastic-search-using-python