# How to get total term frequency through aggregation in elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation

In a search result, I want to get the total number of times a term has showed in the list of documents returned. By only using term aggregations, I can only get the doc count but what I want is the total number of terms occurred across the entire set.

For example:

```
doc1:
Name: David
Tech: A1, A1, B1, B1, C1

doc2: 
Name: Josh
Tech: C1, D1, E1

doc3:
Name: David
Tech: A1, D1, F1
```

when I search for 'David' in the field 'Name' I will normally get my 'Tech' aggregation as:

```
A1: 2
B1: 1
C1: 1
D1: 1
F1: 1
```

whereas I want my results to show:

```
A1: 3
B1: 2
C1: 1
D1: 1
F1: 1
```

Is there anyway I can do this with aggregations?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Setting up the field to have a term vectors gives access to the term count.

Then you can query for any number of document ids

Will give you a list of terms in the document with the count of the occurrence of term in the document and a count of the term in the shard. If you have only one shard then you a good otherwise you can make an estimate of the usage across all shards.

see this [How to retrieve frequency of a term in elastic search using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085839/how-to-retrieve-frequency-of-a-term-in-elastic-search-using-python)